Can I obtain the source TeX file for the published version of my paper in Physical Review
I often publish in the Physical Review journals of the American Physical Society (APS). I usually update the final version of my paper to arXiv after going through the proof corrections. Sometimes, there are tons of proof corrections that I might want to include in the updated arXiv version. It would make my life infinitely simpler if it were possible to just get the source TeX file for the final published version. Has anyone ever heard of APS providing that, or is there a reason they don't?

I'm not sure what they use now, but the APS journals used to use a different markup language for actual production, although they could convert to it directly from LaTeX.

What did APS say when you asked them?

In some journals the edits made during the proof process are technically their "property", and you are only allowed to share the version you sent to the journal. Even propagating the changes they made manually to Arxiv might be breaking their rules.

The comment by @Buzz is correct. My most recent* first-round proofs from Physical Review B contains the statement

All articles, regardless of their original source, are converted into standardized XML, which is then used to create the PDF and online versions of the article as well as to populate third-party systems such as Portico, Crossref, and Web of Science. This process works exceptionally well for most articles; however, please check carefully all key elements of your PDF proof, particularly any equations or tables.

Although it is not stated explicitly, I have always assumed that their production staff then applies proofs corrections to this XML version, in order to not have to repeat the same conversion, possibly introducing errors over and over. Thus, there presumably wouldn't be any updated TeX files to be had.
*APS have used this approach for years, though the wording may have changed over time.

I think the conversion to xml happens after editing. The “redline” proofs provided usually look like straight up revtex. (And typically do not contain any of the goofs introduced by the xml conversion.

@TimRias You may be on to something - the document properties of the redlined proofs for the same paper actually mentions "BaKoMa TeX", which is a WYSIWYG editor. But that makes me more confused about why they redline so much in-line math... Still, I guess author corrections to the proofs would only show up in the XML version.
